# Why django user created via google auth without social application token?

Tags: django, google-api, gmail, django-allauth

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCG70.png)Using django-allauth users signed-in via google API, but social application token is not being created, how to get it?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIX:**
In your project `settings.py` file add `SOCIALACCOUNT_STORE_TOKENS = True`. Its default is set to False, as seen in the *bottom* of the [configuration documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

Had the exact same problem, (probably) due to following old tutorials. Hope this works for you!

Comment: Same problem here!
The variable's name is `SOCIALACCOUNT_STORE_TOKENS` with the `S` at the end.
Here is the updated link to the documentation: https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/socialaccount/configuration.html